# Add a keyboard modifier on Windows

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout

It is possible to add a modifier on a Windows keyboard layout, to have additional keys layers, like in this german keyboard layout neo : https://neo-layout.org/index_en.html ?

And is it possible to bind them to regular key code, like a key, not a real modfier ?

Thanks

Comment: You can make this work with AutoHotKey.  What do you mean by "bind them to regular key code, like a key, not a real modfier"?  How do you intend to turn on each layer?

Comment: I basically want to bind, the scancode that correspond to the "a" key in qwerty, for exemple, to a modifier that can be used to add a new layer.

Comment: Something like pressing Ctrl+1 causes the keyboard to remapped to layer 1, and Ctrl+2 to layer 2, and so on?  Or like it seems in your link that "empty" is layer 1, Shift is layer 2, Caps is layer 3, etc?

Comment: Empty is layer 1, Shift is layer 2, etc, yes.
Because if we put Ctrl+1 to switch on layer 1, it will disturb applications that use Ctrl+<key> shortcut.

Comment: Just to get this straight: are the 16 "layers" you have from using the existing `Ctrl`, `Alt`, `Shift` and `WinKey` modifiers not enough? You want another modifier that would bring this number up to 32 - is that correct?

Comment: I try to add modifiers, and i don't want to use the Ctrl, Alt and Win key as this will disturb programs that handle theses modifiers

Comment: And binding one to the `a` key won't disturb programs that handle that key? I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish here. How do you intend to use this new modifier? Give an example, please.

Comment: No, binding to `a` key was an example.
I try to add a modifier, for exemple, the 0 of the numpad, because i don't use a numpad often.
So can i say to windows that the Numpad 0 need to act as a modifier, and can I configure which key is going to be produced if i do Numpad0 + C(i mean the keycode here, read C as the keycode for C in a qwerty keyboard), for exemple ?